# Drawing points on screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#else
#include <GL/GLUT.h>
#endif

#define heightWindow 500
#define widthWindow 500

struct point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

vector<struct point> arr(heightWindow);

void renderScene();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (struct point& i : arr) {
        i.x = k;
        i.y = k;
        k++;
    }
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(widthWindow, heightWindow);
    glutCreateWindow("2D NBody Problem");
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glPointSize(3.0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 1;
}

void renderScene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    for (struct point& i : arr) {
        glVertex2f(i.x, i.y);
    }
    glEnd();
    glFinish();
    glutSwapBuffers();  
}
```

The way I have set up my code, it should print a diagonal set of points from the upper left to the bottom right. But when I run this, only one point is shown, at the center of the window.

Is there anything that I can do about this?

Comment: You need to setup a projection matrix (orthographic for your case) so that when rendering the vertices are multiplied by that matrix and not the identify matrix (which expects [-1, 1] vertex values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any extra setup OpenGL uses identity transforms for modelview and projection. Which means that your points' coordinates are passed right through to NDC space. NDC space has the value range [-1;1]³, i.e. it is not using absolute device coordinates (pixels), but relative coordinates. That means that every point except the first one, with coordinates (0,0) will be outside the visible range.

So either set up a projection that maps view space coordinates [0,viewport_width]×[0,viewport_height] to [-1;1]² or generate your points in NDC coordinates.

BTW: Drawing single points with OpenGL is rather inefficient. Even more so if immediate mode (glBegin, glVertex, glEnd) is used. Use the proper primitive for a line (GL_LINE) and vertex arrays.

Comment: what's the most efficient way of drawing lots of points in OpenGL?

Comment: Well don't draw *single* points. Put all the points you want to draw into a single vertex array and draw them in a batch using a single `glDrawArrays` call. If you need to draw "big" points (aka, circles), then you'd normally do this using instancing a triangle inscribing the circle and a fragment shader that discards all the fragments outside the circle.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply and a general answer. I've already rewritten my drawing function with glDrawArrays using VBOs, the gain is tremendous judging from the gprof analysis!

Answer (score 0):

Its a scaling issue. All but the first point are drawn outside the canvas.

You need something like

```
        glVertex2f(i.x / widthWindow, i.y / heightWindow);
```

---

As noted by other commenters, this (a) does only give half of the diagonal line and (b) is less elegant than to specify a projection matrix.

The alternative is to do

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, widthWindow, 0, heightWindow, -1, 1);
```

before you call glBegin().

Comment: That scaling is not quire right. OpenGL NDC space has the value range [-1;1].

Comment: Correct, but it addresses the key problem of the OP. With this fix the OP can experiment again and figure out what he wants to show on screen. I think our two answers are intersting. Mine is a bit more hands on, your's is more correct I guess.